# Dojo - destroying tooltip widget when DOM node is destroyed

Tags: javascript, dojo

I use dijit/tooltips on a page that has a lot of domConstuct.destroy() and domConstuct.place() going on. So each time I remove some nodes from the DOM, I want to remove tooltips attached to those nodes. Currently the number of tooltip widgets is constantly growing on my page.

Is there a way to automatically remove a widget when corresponding DOM node is removed, or to check if existing tooltip widget's connect DOM node still exists?

Comment: Can you tell me how you instantiate your tooltips? Do you use `connectId` or `Tooltip.show("...", myNode)` (ad hoc) or by using the `selector` property?

Answer (score 3):

You can attach a single Tooltip widget to multiple nodes at once, this may be the solution for you as you don't have to "manage" your tooltips anymore then. There's only one tooltip widget created for all tooltips, so you don't have to destroy it anymore.

The best way to achieve this is by using the `selector` property as described in the [reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/Tooltip.html#attaching-to-multiple-nodes).

```js
new Tooltip({
    connectId: "myTable",
    selector: "tr",
    getContent: function(matchedNode){
        return matchedNode.getAttribute("tooltipText");
    }
});
```

If they don't have a common `connectId` and/or `selector`, then you can still use a single tooltip by adding the target to the same tooltip instance by using the [`addTarget()`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dijit/Tooltip#1_9dijit_Tooltip_addTarget) function.

To remove a target you can also use `removeTarget()` which accepts a DOM node (so you just pass the DOM node you want to remove).

---

If neither of these solutions is able to help you I'd like to know how you instantiate your tooltips, there are multiple ways to do that. For example by using `connectId` or by creating an ad hoc tooltip using the `show()` function.

Comment: I was creating a new instance of Tooltip for every connectId, I didn't even know about selector property. I could now say that the problem is with the Dojo documentation (which I very often find confusing and non-informative), but the truth is, I didn't read the documentation on this matter in details. Anyway, very good answer, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I now realized I still have a similar, if not the same problem. The number of tooltips will not grow, but the number of connects will. If I destroy a DOM node containing multiple nodes that have tooltip connections, I would have to check for each of the descendant nodes if it had a connection to tooltip so I can remove it as a target before I destroy the DOM node. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution to my problem with a help of Dimitri's answer. I don't create separate Tooltip widget for each tooltip any more, now I put all the tooltips in one Tooltip using it's .addTarget() method. The second part of the solution is iterating through Tooltip's connectId property and checking if the DOM node still exists. I had to do it using Javascript native methods .contains() and .getElementById(), because Dojo's dom.byId() and query() gave me false positives. So, my code now looks like this:

```
// creating Tooltip
var tooltips = new Tooltip({
    getContent: function(matchedNode){
        return matchedNode.getAttribute("tooltiptext");
    }
});

// adding tooltips
tooltips.addTarget(nameNode);

// deleting sufficient connects
for(var i = tooltips.connectId.length -1; i >= 0 ; i--){
    if(!document.contains(tooltips.connectId[i]) && !document.getElementById(tooltips.connectId[i])){
        tooltips.removeTarget(tooltips.connectId[i]);
    }
}
```

The reason I had to use both .contains() and .getElementById() is that some of the nodes I attached tooltips to have ids and some don't, and Tooltip widget stores some of them as strings (id) and some as DOM nodes.